# React - I need to save package.json again and again beetween compilatons

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

I compiled my react project with npm start and it's showing the following error:

```
Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\Abc\Desktop\project\blog-mern\frontend\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\Abc\Desktop\Project\Blog-Mern\frontend\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
```

I need to save package.json again and again beetween compilatons to make it work.
Is there is any permenent solution for this?

Comment: Share the mvp or a hello world replicating the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Consider Basic react-app ( npx i create-react-app myApp )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me since i´ve started to work with react the last week. Try to use a different console, if you use PowerShell change to Cmd (windows only)

I think it´s because of path name resolving.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).